# faultCode:Client.Error.RequestTimeout adobe air

Tags: apache-flex, air, httpservice

I'm getting a wierd problem when the internet connections are changed from wireless to ethernet cable and viceversa, as per the users it is occuring rarely 3 out of 10 times, but we cannot avoid it. When I debug the problem i get the following error when connecting.

faultCode:Client.Error.RequestTimeout faultString:'Request timed out' faultDetail:'The request timeout for the sent message was reached without receiving a response from the server.'

Also the httpservice code is pasted below. Thanks. How to avoid this error when the networks are changed?

```
                                              var httpConfigService:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
                                    httpConfigService.url = serverUrl + Model.SERVER_CONFIG_NAME ;
                                    httpConfigService.requestTimeout = 10;
                                    httpConfigService.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, handleConfigResult);
                                    httpConfigService.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, handleConfigFault);
                                    httpConfigService.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well.. if the service times out then it times out.. there is nothing you can do about that except for example increase your timeout limit so that the service waits for a longer period (hopefully long enough for the connection to switch from wireless to wired and vice-versa).